# Why Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I am going to school for Database Administration and Design. There I learn SQL Server, SSRS, SSIS and SSAS and some other technologies. My question is: Is there any real value in learning MS Access for designing databases, especially when I can spend same amount of time on SQL Server and get better at it? Is MS Access still relevant in the job market?

Cheers,

Comment: This is too opinionated to be on topic on SO.

Comment: If you have zero knowledge of SQL queries and no other database to play with it's an ok start.  to get the basic select, from where group by having order by syntax.  It also works ok for small businesses < 10 man shops beyond that enterprise db's make more sense imo.

Comment: So at this stage I am NOT zero at SQL queries, but not super confident in claiming that I can write them fluently either.

Comment: Stick with the mainstream DBMSs (SQL Server, Oracle, etc). Access is niche, non-standard and it lacks most of the features you ought to be learning about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would not compare Visual Studio or vb.net to SQL server. So Access has two parts:

ACE

ACE is the replacement database engine for JET – they are much the same.

MS Access

MS Access is a developer’s tool. You can write a space invaders game or say write a chess game in Access. So you can’t replace Access with SQL server since SQL server does not allow you to create a GUI front end and deploy it to each windows workstation.

So access is a software development tool that allows you to create a windows desktop program. Comparing or suggesting to use Access or SQL server in this context makes ZERO sense.

Access makes a great front end to say Oracle, or MySQL or SQL server. You can also choose to use the built in database engine called ACE, but you certainly not limited to that choice. Access is thus a tool that "connects" to some type of database system.

So you can well ignore the other advice here, since such advice fails to distinguish between a tool to create software like MS Access and that of a database engine + system. You can't really suggest to use SQL server in place of Access. One could perhaps suggest to drop the use of ACE and say adopt a server based database engine such as SQL server.

So advice that fails to make such a distinction is based on advice that does not make the distinction between a developer’s tools like Visual Studio, FoxPro or say MS Access. These tools allow one to build windows desktop applications. SQL server, oracle, MySQL etc. have no such ability.

In effect you comparing apples and oranges.

You can’t replace Access with SQL server or say MySQL since those systems are database servers and database engines.

Access allows the creating of full featured windows desktop programs and any kind of comparison to SQL server makes no sense at all here.

You can certainly download and use the ACE connectivity database engine as a 100% separate install and use the ACE database engine with say VB6, FoxPro or MS Access the software development and creating tool. So the database engine ACE is available as a separate download from that of Access.

Perhaps someone here can attempt to explain how you create windows desktop programs with SQL server say as compared to FoxPro or Visual Studio or MS Access. Once this kind of difference is pointed out, one can clearly see that using Access or FoxPro or vb.net in the context replacing SQL server does not make sense.

Comment: Thankd Albert, that was eye opening

Comment: @Albert No one suggested using SQL Server for creating "Windows desktop programs". The question here is very specifically whether to use Access for learning about database administration and design. My answer is no. The limitations and peculiarities of both Access and Jet/ACE make them a poor choice for that particular purpose.

Comment: But any suggest to replace Access with SQL server and FAILING to note the difference between the two implies that you can replace Access with SQL server - that is NOT possible and not the case. Telling someone to drop Access and use SQL server without noting that SQL server does not create a GUI nor has no GUI interface fails on all accounts. The omission of such information makes such information useless. And more to the point you can use Access as a front end to SQL server or oracle - so using Access does not imply nor suggest you are limited to using the ACE database engine.

Comment: No one remotely suggested dropping or replacing Access. The question was whether to begin using Access for learning about database admin and design. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc all have excellent UI's for admin and design already.

Comment: Never stated or claimed any one is going to drop Access. Context issue was using SQL server (+ tools) or something like Access. No one is going to ask if they should replace a airplane with a bicycle. You can "try" and make the case both are used for transportation, but failing to point out one can fly and other does not is MOST important. Or in this case that of a software development tool vs a database system is quite much the whole point and ball of wax here. Access is NOT a database anymore then VB6 or Visual studio is. This all important distinguishing point remains critical here.